# need help in PHP soap

Tags: php, soap

i try to fetch result from www.tadawul.com.sa with php soap client.

but when i try to load that , get nothing just loading page.

here is my code.

```
$reference = array(
             'companyId' => '*********',
             'secureKey' => '*********'
        );

        $client = new SoapClient('http://www.tadawul.com.sa/Tadawul_WebAPI/services/GetDetailQuote?wsdl');
        $response = $client->getDetailQuoteForCompany($reference);
        var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Did you look at your error logs? Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: it didn't show any error. here is my live link  http://spimaco.com.sa/

Comment: I GET THIS ERROR 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: SoapClient::SoapClient(): SSL: Connection reset by peer

Filename: libraries/Stock.php

Line Number: 46

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.tadawul.com.sa/Tadawul_WebAPI/services/GetDetailQuote?wsdl' : StartTag: invalid element name in /home/--------/Stock.php:46 Stack trace: #0 /home/----------------/Stock.php(46): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://www.tada...') #1 /home/---------homepage.php(33):

Comment: Stock->showStocks() #2 [internal function]: Homepage->index() #3 /home/-----/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 /home/----------/index.php(203): require_once('/home/spimacoco...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/-------/Stock.php on line 46

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the structure you need to pass a getDetailQuoteForCompanyRequest Object not an array
Why don't you use [wsdl2phpgenerator](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator)

It'll make you life easier, You need to pass wsdl file and it will generate all the classes that you need

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
$response = $client->getDetailQuoteForCompany($reference);
```

Try

```
$response = $client->__soapCall("getDetailQuoteForCompany", array($reference));
```

Comment: i try your code but getting same issue. let me show you live url

Comment: if by now you where unable to fix this please take a look in this post https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api/nely_4Vl_No maybe it will be helpful. @MuhammadAlsahelsolutel